# Как можно узнать дату событий которые повторяются?

Tags: php

(раз в неделю, раз в две недели, раз в месяц)
пишу на php календарь известна дата создания события в виде (год-месяц-день) .Можете объяснить как это можно сделать?

Comment: раз в неделю, раз в две недели, раз в месяц пишу на php - это к вопросу относится? что за события? из вопроса не ясно что именно вам нужно. распишите детальнее, не бойтесь привести пример.

Answer (score 1):

См. функцию [`date_add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-add.php)

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2014-05-09');

addInterval( $date, '10 days'); // 10 дней
addInterval( $date, '5 weeks'); // 5 недель
addInterval( $date, '1 month'); // 1 месяц
addInterval( $date, '2 years'); // 2 года

function addInterval( $date, $interval){
    $newDate = clone $date;
    date_add($newDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string( $interval));
    printf( "%s + \"%s\" = %s\n",
        date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'),
        $interval,
        date_format($newDate, 'Y-m-d')
    );
}
```

Вывод:

```
2014-05-09 + "10 days" = 2014-05-19
2014-05-09 + "5 weeks" = 2014-06-13
2014-05-09 + "1 month" = 2014-06-09
2014-05-09 + "2 years" = 2016-05-09
```

[работающий пример](http://ideone.com/PmzvEM)

Answer (score 0):

Для месяца, года, дня:

Берете исходную дату. Достаете год/месяц, в зависимости от периодичности. Заменяете на новое значение. Используете strToTime чтобы перевести в unixtime.

Для еженедельных:

В сутках 24 часа, то есть 24*60*60 секунд.
В неделе - 7*24*60*60 секунд.
Переводите при помощи strToTime дату в unixtime, прибавляете вот то самое магическое число секунд в неделе, умноженное на число недель и переводите обратно в дату.

Comment: Если бы все так просто было! : ))

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Увы, на данный момент возможности посмотреть полноценно видео нет.